# How to deploy the payment gateway into real environment?

Tags: react-native, paypal, payment-gateway

I have integrated payment gateway in my react-native app by using "react-native-paypal-wrapper".
How to test and deploy it in real environment? Right now, when I enter any wrong email and password, then it passes. I think my code is for test.

That is my code. How to make it work in real environment?

```
_onPay = () => {
  const options = {
    merchantName: "sss",
    merchantPrivacyPolicyUri: "https://example.com/privacy",
    merchantUserAgreementUri: "https://example.com/useragreement",
  }
  PayPal.initialize(PayPal.NO_NETWORK, PAY_PAL_CLIENT_ID);
  // PayPal.obtainConsent().then(authorization => console.log('authorization', authorization))
  //   .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  // const metadataID = await PayPal.getClientMetadataId();
  PayPal.pay({
    price: '19.99',
    currency: "USD",
    description: "19.99 USD will be paid",
  })
    .then((confirm) => {
      console.log('confirm', confirm);
      this.setState({ isPaid: true })
      Alert.alert("Congratulation!", " 19.99 USD was paid.");
      // this.paymentHandler(confirm.response, subscription_id, days, userID);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.message !== "User cancelled") {
        Alert.alert(error.message);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-wrapper) of the 2-year-old package you are using?

```
// 3 env available: NO_NETWORK, SANDBOX, PRODUCTION
PayPal.initialize(PayPal.NO_NETWORK, "<your-client-id>");
```

In addition to specifying PRODUCTION there, the place to obtain a production client ID is from the 'Live' tab of an application in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: Thank you. Then what is the merchantPrivacyPolicyUri & merchantUserAgreementUri & obtainConsent & metadataID ?  I can't find the explanation of those options.

Comment: Used by future payments. Which you aren't using.

Comment: If I use webview method, how to deploy the sandbox to real payment ?

Comment: No idea what you mean by webview method, but every single integration method has a way to specify the environment

Comment: Really Thank you for your kind answer. Actually I followed this reference.
https://medium.com/zestgeek/paypal-integration-in-react-native-9d447df4fce1
As you can see in the final code block, line 47, line 60, line 96 are all use sandbox URL.
In my app, if user click "Buy" button, it takes user to the sandbox page in webview.
That's why in that page, if I enter real paypal login information, then it gives me error.
How to deploy to real paypal ? I am struggling to find out the exact solution on the Internet, but almost reference are for virtual payment integration.

Comment: None of them teach me how to integrate real payment. Is there any exact solution to integrate real payment + RN app ? Also is there any reference to refund money from paypal in RN app?

Comment: "As you can see in the final code block, line 47, line 60, line 96 are all use sandbox URL." -- so, don't use sandbox URLs. What are you confused about?

Comment: Then may I just remove the word "sandbox" in the URL ?
I have tried like that, but it didn't work. I thought there is another link or method. Am I right?

Comment: "It didn't work"? Where is the specific detail of your problem description. Are you using a live clientID and secret?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224827/discussion-between-satelbill-and-preston-phx).

Comment: With your help I solved this problem. I changed with live clientID and secret key, and it was worked. But in the final step (in the final code block line 96), I removed "sandbox", but it didn't work. (Also I modified line 94. It was wrong-that line needs some javascript string operation to get PayerID and paymentID). How to solve this final error?
I got these errors in final step.
 - 404 Not Found
 - Error loading page
 - Domain: undefined
 - Error Code: 2
 - Description: SSL error: Hostname mismatch